# Format of Data Dictionary

Tags: excel, data-dictionary

I have been creating a data dictionary with each table having a separate Excel sheet.

However now I've got so many tables that using the tabs has become cumbersome.

Has anyone got any suggestions to make them more manageable?

Thanks

Comment: From what you've said.... maybe a database rather than a spreadsheet?  Other than that can you provide some more details please?  What do you mean by a `data dictionary`?  What's the structure?  Are you using formula, pivot tables, vba?  [mcve]

Comment: It's pretty basic but the dictionary contains information about integrating one database to another.

Each table was on a separate spreadsheet the each row having about 20 columns for each type of description e.g. Name, Type, Description, Name in new database, Type in new database etc.

We liked having a spreadsheet as it was easy to read and edit but having so many tables made it hard to navigate. Maybe having an "index" on the first sheet with hyperlinks to all the tabs may be a solution?

Comment: Could you expand a lot please - the only extra info you've provided there is that there's _about_ 20 columns for each type of description.  Are you using VBA code?  Formula? How do the tabs link together to make a database?  Are there any kind of key values linking sheets together?

Comment: My main issue is having to scroll the tabs in Excel, there are so many you can't see them all at the same time so navigating is difficult. I was hoping that an Excel expert would be able to suggest a way around this.

Comment: If you _right-click_ the arrows to the left of the tabs you'll get a list of the first 15 tab names and a _more sheets_ option to open a dialog box of sheet names.  Is that along the lines of what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that is really helpful, thanks Darren!

Answer (score 0):

I think  Darren Bartrup-Cook's answer should do it.

If you right-click the arrows to the left of the tabs you'll get a list of the first 15 tab names and a more sheets option to open a dialog box of sheet names.

(Darren I'm trying to work out how to say your comment was the answer but this was the best I could do)

Comment: That's fine.  Just tick this as the accepted answer - not sure if you can do it straight away, or have to wait a while though.